# python readline and asynchronous printing

Tags: python, asynchronous, readline

I'm building a command line tool where the user can enter commands and to make command editing more pleasant I use `readline`.  Also there can be important events happening in other threads which must be printed to the console. However simply printing them with `print()` messes up the readline prompt. Is there a way to print a line without messing up readline? Here's an example:

```py
import readline
from threading import Timer

def event():
    print('Async event happened!')

t = Timer(3, event)
t.start()

a = input('CLI> ')
print('You entered:', a)
```

If I type in `start` but don't press enter yet and then wait for the event to happen, then the console will look like this (`_` is the cursor):

```
CLI> startAsync event happened!
_
```

But I'd like it to look like the following:

```
Async event happened!
CLI> start_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty sure you can't do this with the `readline` interface exposed via the standard library, if you have some flexibility in using other libraries you could try the [prompt toolkit](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/) package that comes with a context manager that patches things up nicely so they just work as you hope:

```
from prompt_toolkit import prompt
from prompt_toolkit.patch_stdout import patch_stdout
import threading

def fn():
    print('async event')

with patch_stdout():
    threading.Timer(3, fn).start()
    a = prompt('Cli> ')

print('got', repr(a))
```

just works for me

note that this sort of thing breaks various aspects of unix TTY handling, so will always tend to be delicate/easy to break.  the abstraction behind things is still based around a "console" being a ["teletype" device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter) (i.e. a typewriter going to paper) so sending plain text out will just work, but interactive editing (even within a single line) is kind of a hack.  that said, it should mostly work

Comment: `prompt_toolkit` works perfectly, thank you very much! My application is quite simple so I don't think there will be any problems. And it's good to know that this package can also do more advanced things in case I ever need that.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a lock to print it orderly.

```
import threading

print_lock = threading.Lock()

def thread1():
...
    with print_lock:
        print('blabla')

def thread2():
...
    with print_lock:
        print('bla')
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps. You don't include any `input()` or `readline` in your example.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what is included. My point is that you can control your asynchronous events to print things orderly with a lock. The only thing you must try is add the print_lock before your prints.

Comment: My problem is not the ordering. It's the `readline` prompt getting messed up. My example wasn't subject to a race condition that could be resolved with a mutex. I think you misunderstood the issue.

Comment: I'm running it on jupyter notebook, guess your problem is not a thing here. Running it through my console, I think I got what you mean. Only thing I could imagine is using 'print('\nAsync event happened!')' to separate in the case where you don't press Enter. You could filter it out somehow if 'enter' is pressed.